# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch when create new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Got ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch`Component(#70354292616060) expected, got String(#70354278277000)` when create object "Machine" below;

**Objective**: Try to assign "attributes" to a model that is referred to the other model.

**Question**: I would like to hear from expert that what is the best practice for this kind of operation.

**Settings**:

Rails 3.2.12 / Ruby 1.9.3-p194:

Models:

```
class Machine < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cpu, :name, :ram

  belongs_to :cpu, class_name: "Component", foreign_key: "component_id"
  belongs_to :ram, class_name: "Component", foreign_key: "component_id"
end

class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :machines
end
```

Views for Machine:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :cpu %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :cpu, Component.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :ram %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :ram, Component.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

**Procedure**:

1. Create few objects to Component such that `id:1 name:"cpu1"` & `id:2 name:"ram1"`
2. Go to machines_path and create Machine with selecting cpu1 and ram1 from pull down
3. Got following error when submit `Component(#70354292616060) expected, got String(#70354278277000)`

I tried to change :cpu and :ram in View with :cpu_id and :ram_id. Thereafter, I can create the model without error.  However I cannot access cpu & ram directly from machine;

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > Machine.first
  Machine Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "machines".* FROM "machines" LIMIT 1
 => #<Machine id: 2, name: "test", cpu_id: 1, ram_id: 1, created_at: "2013-05-06     16:42:47", updated_at: "2013-05-06 16:42:47"> 
1.9.3-p194 :002 > Machine.first.cpu
  Machine Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "machines".* FROM "machines" LIMIT 1
 => nil 
1.9.3-p194 :003 > Machine.first.ram
  Machine Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "machines".* FROM "machines" LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

So I had to create following model methods

```
  class Machine < ActiveRecord::Base

  (snip)

  def cpu
    Component.find_by_id(self.cpu_id)
  end

  def ram
    Component.find_by_id(self.ram_id)
  end
```

Then I can get expected output

```
1.9.3-p194 :002 > Machine.first.cpu.name
  Machine Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "machines".* FROM "machines" LIMIT 1
  Component Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "components".* FROM "components" WHERE "components"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  => "CPU1"
```

But I feel it's redundant and looking for a simpler way to do this.

Appreciate if any suggestions.

Comment: You should take a look at nested_attributes ;)

Comment: Thanks MrYoshiji for your suggestion, will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, having your select boxes work with cpu_id and ram_id is the right thing to do. If you don't then rails will (simplifying slightly) do

```
machine.cpu = params[:machine][:cpu]
```

Params are always strings, so this is trying to assign a string to the association, hence the error about it expecting a component but getting a string.

Your second problem is in how you've declared your associations: you've set both ram and cpu associations to use the component_id column to store the id of the corresponding column, which clearly can't work. Instead you probably want the CPU association to use the cpu_id column and the ram association the ram_id column. This is actually the default - remove the foreign key option you're passing to those calls to belongs to and you should be ok.

You associations on component would need a foreign key option though. The simplest thing would be to have one association for the machines that the component acts as CPU for and another for the ram. You might consider setting up single table inheritance, in which case the CPU subclass would only have the association relating to cpu_id and the ram subclass would only have the association relating to ram_id

Comment: Thanks a lot Fredrick for your advice. It worked as all expected after changed foreign key. (without having redundant model method).

Answer (score 0):

So, if i'm reading this right, you need to be able to set fields to the other model from within your form.

That's nested attributes.

do a `form_for @components` within the `form_for @machines` and give `attr_accessible` permissions to those fields from the `Machine` model

This is helpful http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: I shouldn't omit that portion. form_for and attr_accessible are set. table for Machine have a column called "cpu_id:integer" and "ram_id:integer" and attr_accessible: :cpu_id, :ram_id.